# Function not called post Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am using nodejs with mondodb but facing a weird situation without any errors.

I call the updateUsers function with the callback but the updateDashboard function is not getting called at all even on successful completion of updateUsers function. The code blocks are below. There are no errors reported as well.

```
                updateUsers(data,dashboardDayData.key,function(err,doc){

                        updateDashboard(dashboardYearData,data.type,1,doc,function(err){console.log("Got executed");});

                });


function updateUsers(req,dateKey,callback){
        var yyyy        = parseInt(dateKey.toString().substring(0,4));
        var mm          = parseInt(dateKey.toString().substring(4,6));
        var dd          = dateKey.toString().substring(6,8);
        switch(req.type){
                case Collection["begin"]:
                        Model.User.findById(req.val.did,function(err,doc){
                                if(!err){
                                        if(doc === null || !doc){
                                                req.type = Collection["user"];
                                                req.val.ts = 1;
                                                req.val.tts = 0;
                                                event = EventFactory.getEvent(req);
                                                event.save(function (err) {
                                                        if (err) {
                                                                logger.error(common.getErrorMessageFrom(err));
                                                                return;
                                                        }
                                                        var push = {};
                                                        push['_'+yyyy] = JSON.parse('{"_id":'+parseInt(mm.toString().concat(dd))+',"tse":1,"tts":0}');
                                                        Model.User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.val.did,{$push:push},{upsert:true},function(err,doc){
                                                                console.log("err "+err);
                                                                console.log("doc "+doc);
                                                                if(err){
                                                                        logger.error(common.getErrorMessageFrom(err));
                                                                        return;
                                                                }

                                                                                                                                callback(err,1);
                                                        });
                                                });
```

}

```
function updateDashboard(dashboardData,eventType,valueIncrement,newUserIncrement,callback){
        switch(eventType){
                case Collection["begin"]:
                        console.log(dashboardData);
                        Model.Dashboard.findByIdAndUpdate(dashboardData,{$inc:{'val.tse':valueIncrement,'val.tnu':newUserIncrement}},{upsert:true},function(err,doc){
                                if(err){
                                        logger.error(err);
                                }
                        callback(err);
                        });
                        break;
```

Comment: so, you get the err and doc console logs happening?

Comment: Yes, it happens. The flow is as expected where err and doc gets printed after Model.User.findByIdAndUpdate function and callback(err,1) gets executes but the updateDashboard doesn't gets executed.

Comment: So you get to the anonymous function in line 1 of the code you posted, but `updateDashboard` never gets called? or is it that the callback of updateDashboard never gets called?

Comment: @Vaibs: Sorry I did not understand your query. Please elaborate and I will provide the details.

Comment: @Jaromanda X : neither of it happens . I did console.log("Inside dashboard") within the updateDashboard function but even that is not displayed.

Comment: please post at least the start of updateDashboard

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors at all reported.

Comment: console.log above `updateDashboard` works?

Comment: Yes console.log works above updateDashboard. even the callback value which is 1 gets printed.

Comment: have you managed to add the code for updateDashboard? seems that's the most likely place you have an error

Comment: Added above. Please check

Comment: and a console.log before the first statement in that function never gets called?

Comment: the console.log in the updatedashboard function doesn't get printed.

Comment: I don't mean where you've put it, I mean if you console.log before the switch

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Can you please help me with the question again?

Comment: put console.log statement before switch statement in updateDashboard function ... i.e. as the first line of the function ... does console.log get called if you make that change

Comment: Yes I had put the same but it doesn't get executed. I had specifically put before the switch to validate the same.

Comment: You were right Jaromanda X!!!!!!!!!. Thanks for your support. I had put the console in the wrong place. It seems the value eventtype is being passed incorrectly because of variable scope issue. Again ton thanks for your support..

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem sleeps in the anonymous function called at your first `updateUsers` declaration. If I'm guessing right, JavaScript attends three objects as parameters for your `function updateUsers(req,dateKey,callback)`, and I think this piece of code:

```
function(err,doc){   
  updateDashboard(dashboardYearData,data.type,1,doc,function(err)   {console.log("Got executed");}); 
}
```

is not interpreted as an object. So he thinks you never call this function. Once again, I'm only trying to guess, but I think the problem is there. Try fo encapsulate your function in an object, then calling it ? Somethink like :

```
var subfunction = function(err, doc) { updateDashboard (...) };
updateUsers(req, database, subfunction);
```

Comment: why wouldn't the function be interpreted as a function? what would it be interpreted as? a hat? a paperclip?

Comment: Edited, let me breath please.

Comment: you're right though, that function would not be interpreted as an Object, as it is a function

Comment: @Yassine : You just moved it to a non-anonymous function. correct? I will try that but still not understanding why its not getting executed.

Comment: That is correct, and it didn't solve the problem, hmm ... If you have time, try to post a JSFiddle or something so that we can experiment too.